# Dynamics CRM : Editing the opportunities created by other owners

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to find a long-term solution to edit the opportunities created by other owner in the following scenarios.

1. Our team consist of 4 members who creates the opportunities in CRM. If any one of the owners is on vacation, then the backup team member cannot edit the opportunities created by others (if required)
   -> At present each time we have to ask for the permission to admin to edit the record. At times it takes long time to get the approval and the person is blocked

Please let me know how we can fix the issue and unblock the backup person.

Thanks!
Aq

Can we automate it and streamline the process of having edit permissions for the backup up for the opportunities created in Dynamics CRM by specific people in the team?

Comment: One possible way is to change the read/create/modify opportunity privilege from user level to business level.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

1. Increase the role privileges for opportunity to BU level, which
   makes everyone read every opportunity in the system. Might have
   implications on your security matrix.
2. Another Approach would be to have a table called as Leave Log and
   let user choose who is the backup for them and duration. You can
   have approvals if required.

   - Create a power automate to get all opportunities (filter which you want to share may be open and in-progress only) and share with the new user.
   - There should be another power automate to revoke access to the user at end of leave period (could be recurring Power automate).
   - This option you are just sharing the require opportunity during the period of absence and not violating the security matrix you already have.